# How to convert javascript to matlab. Also how should one run the javascript from matlab?

Tags: javascript, matlab

How to make .js run from Matlab file?

If required, is it possible to make modificationS in the .js file while running from matlab?

Answer (score 1):

You can run anything that your PC could run using `system`. Basically call whatever program will run the .js file with it.

About making modifications: I don't think there exists a programming language/compiler/interpreter on where you can modify the code while its running! I doubt javascript can do that.